# error with angular view with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I have a small node project that I'm trying to integrate angularjs into. I have a partial view which uses ng-controller and ng-repeat.

Here is my angular.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"/>
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view3">view3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="services.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="filters.js"></script>
  <script src="directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

partial3.html (this is the partial):

```
      <div ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
          {{person.last}} , {{person.first}}
      </div>
```

I just get 5 commas without the five records in the person controller.

```
  .controller('PersonCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [
        { first: "Henry", middle: "Jacob", last: "Mendocino", gender: "M" },
        { first: "Ann", middle: "Cecilia", last: "Negro", gender: "F" },
        { first: "Berta", middle: "Ann", last: "Sallyfield", gender: "F" },
        { first: "Rudolf", middle: "John", last: "Waters", gender: "M" },
        { first: "Ken", middle: "Adam", last: "Aundry", gender: "M" },
    ]
  }])
```

Here is my app.js

```
'use strict';


    // Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
    angular.module('myApp', [
      'ngRoute',
      'myApp.filters',
      'myApp.services',
      'myApp.directives',
      'myApp.controllers'
    ]).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
      $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
      $routeProvider.when('/view3', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial3.html', controller: 'PersonCtrl'});
      $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
    }]);
```

Can someone please help me figure out why my data isn't being showed.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in your browser's devtools console?

Comment: Hi Paul, no errors in console at all. Thanks

Comment: I don't see where you're bootstrapping the angular app, is there a file you're not including in the scripts?

Comment: looks like the only one that will work now is `/view3` do you have `MyCtrl1/MyCtrl2` controllers? or are u just not showing that code?

Comment: also since you have `controller: 'PersonCtrl'` in your routeprovider you dont need it here - `<div ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
          {{person.last}} , {{person.first}}
      </div>` all you need is `<div>
        <div ng-repeat="person in persons">
          {{person.last}} , {{person.first}}
      </div>`

Comment: I'm not sure where I would do that. I'm new to angularjs and this is a working example I grabbed "angular-seed app" which is working fine. I didn't change anything from the original files. I just added these files in my node project and can't get it working. the original example when I run npm start works as expected.

Comment: @ewizard Yes I have them both just not showing here. I went ahead and removed "<div ng-controller="PersonCtrl">" but still get the same results. Thanks

Comment: one last thing - ill edit my answer - i think u are missing ng-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He/She needed to arrange his/her filesystem and express code to point to the right places...most importantly - he/she needed:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
```

so that the app knew where to serve the static content from (index.html).

Comment: This still gives me the same results. Just five commas :(

Comment: messed up syntax...use what i just changed it to.

Comment: Sorry the edit is still giving me the same end results. No data displayed.

Comment: do you have your dev console open?

Comment: where do you have your PersonCtrl code? like what file?

Comment: I want to make sure you have that in the correct place.

Comment: you can literally copy and paste `.controller('PersonCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [
        { first: "Henry", middle: "Jacob", last: "Mendocino", gender: "M" },
        { first: "Ann", middle: "Cecilia", last: "Negro", gender: "F" },
        { first: "Berta", middle: "Ann", last: "Sallyfield", gender: "F" },
        { first: "Rudolf", middle: "John", last: "Waters", gender: "M" },
        { first: "Ken", middle: "Adam", last: "Aundry", gender: "M" },
    ]
  }])` and put it in app.js right after the end of the config block

Comment: PerconCtrl is in the controllers.js file and yes I have my dev console open and all i get is this. XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3005/partials/partial3.html". angular.js:8445
(anonymous function) angular.js:8445
sendReq angular.js:8248
$http.serverRequest angular.js:7980... ect no errros.

Comment: post your controllers.js file

Comment: post all of it - i want to see if u are declaring the module right

Comment: in controller.js you need something like `angular.module('myApp')` before `.controler(...`

Comment: When I put the controller in the app.js file like you suggested I get errros.

Comment: ok - what errors? i updated your fiddle - what happens when you do what i put?

Comment: wait - what i did didnt save on the fiddle - one sec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55934/discussion-between-ewizard-and-fpena06).